# Wordpress call a core function inside of a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am trying to develop a plugin for wordpress where at first I have to get the currency configured in woocommerce. When I try to save `$string = get_woocommerce_currency();` I get a fatal error saying that the function `get_woocommerce_currency();` is not defined. How can I get this value to get it and use it inside my plugin?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer, you only have to `get_option('woocommerce_currency');` like this `$woo_currency = get_option('woocommerce_currency');`